# PyMongo full text search of items in a list

Tags: python, pymongo, tornado-motor

I am looking to do a text search using PyMongo for some items that are embedded within a list. My database is structured as follows:
`{_id:"148319665188372481" }, "tags": ['#123456', '#789012'}`

I want to search my database specifically for the phrase "123456" but because the items are embedded in  a list... I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Here is my current code:

```
        accounts.create_index([('tags', pymongo.TEXT)])
        async for something in accounts.find({"$text": {"$search": "123456"}}):
            print('Entered loop')
            print(something)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created your text index on the `tags` field, but your data is in the `items` field.

You can only create one text index, per collection, but you can add multiple fields if needed; this example creates an index on both `tags` and `items` fields:

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.accounts.create_index([('tags', pymongo.TEXT), ('items', pymongo.TEXT)])
db.accounts.insert_one({"items": ['apple', 'orange', 'peach']})

for something in db.accounts.find({"$text": {"$search": 'apple'}}):
    print(something)
```

result:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e3f03992a4d2cf213983fe3'), 'items': ['apple', 'orange', 'peach']}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I updated my original post with the code using your suggestions, but I can't seem to get the code to run in the async for loop (the "entered loop" statement doesn't even print.

Comment: Hi Will - that's a different question. I suggest you mark this one as answered and start a new question tagged `[python-asyncio]`. You will need to add the remainder of the code for the async setup and say which async libraries you are using.